# How to ECSlidingViewController without storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want to use ECSlidingViewController in my iOS 4.3 applications.
And I wonder how to apply this library without storyboard?

PLZ, how to?  this is my code, but iOS simulator's screen is white only.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrontViewController" bundle:nil];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RearViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    // create a DDMenuController setting the content as the root
    //DDMenuController *menuController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navigationController];
    //menuController.leftViewController = rearViewController;

    //RevealController *menuController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:rearViewController];

    ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    slidingViewController.topViewController = navigationController;
    slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = rearViewController;

    self.window.rootViewController = slidingViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Here is your code**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrontViewController" bundle:nil];
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RearViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] init];
slidingViewController.topViewController = navigationController;
slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = rearViewController;

self.window.rootViewController = slidingViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ECSlidingViewController uses iOS5, Storyboard and ARC. To put efforts into reengineering this class, I suggest you choose other classes which are ready for lower iOS versions and not using Storyboard. Some similar examples are:

https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController
https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue in your code above is that the slidingViewController isn't being instantiated.

You need this line:

```
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = [[ECSlidingViewController alloc] init];
```